# How do I prevent pyspark from interpreting commas as a delimiter in a csv field having JSON object as its value

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am trying to read a comma delimited csv file using pyspark version 2.4.5 and Databrick's spark-csv module. One of the field in the csv file has a json object as its value. The contents of the csv are as below

#### test.csv

```
header_col_1, header_col_2, header_col_3
one, two, three
one, {“key1”:“value1",“key2”:“value2",“key3”:“value3”,“key4”:“value4"}, three
```

Other solutions that I found had read options defined as *"escape": '"'*, and *'delimiter': ","*. This seems not to be working as the commas in the field in question are not enclosed in double quotes. Below is the source code that I am using to read the csv file

#### test.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import findspark

findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

read_options = {
    'header': 'true',
    "escape": '"',
    'delimiter': ",",
    'inferSchema': 'false',
}

spark_df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(**read_options).load('test.csv')

print(spark_df.show())
```

Output of the above program is as shown below

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|header_col_1|     header_col_2|   header_col_3|
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
|         one|              two|          three|
|         one| {“key1”:“value1"|“key2”:“value2"|
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSV file, you have to put the JSON string in straight double quotes. The double quotes in your JSON string must be escaped by backslashes (\"). Remove your escape option as it is incorrect. By default, the delimiter is set to "," the escape character to '\' and the quote character to '"'. Refer to [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html)

Comment: I have no control over the contents of the csv file so I cant manipulate the values before correctly reading them

Comment: @ftchidzix if the CSV file is invalid and you can't fix it, you might need to read the file in as text with `spark.read.text()` and then parse out your desired columns.

Comment: Managed to get it working by first reading the file as text  using ```spark.read.text``` as suggested by @Powers. I was then able to encapsulate the json object in double quotes as recommended by @Janis's.

Comment: @ftchidzix - can you please post an answer to your own question with a code snippet?  That'll make it easier for future readers to know how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

*Delimiters between double quotes are ignored by default*.

The solution to the issue is not so elegant and I guess it can be improved. What worked for me was a two-step process, the first step was reading the file as text using  pyspark `spark.read.text()` method. The the second step involved manipulating the Json object by replacing any double quotes inside the object with single quotes, wrap whole object in double quotes and then write the contents to a new csv file which I then read using the `spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(**read_options).load('new.csv')` method.

Below is the code snippet for the program

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


read_options = {
    'header': 'true',
    'escape': '"',
    'delimiter': ",",
    'inferSchema': 'false',
}


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

lines = sc.textFile("test.csv").collect()

new_data = [
    line.replace(' ', '').replace('“', "'").replace('”',  "'").replace('"',  "'").replace('{', '"{').replace('}', '}"') + '\n'
    for line in lines]

with open('new.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.writelines(new_data)

spark_df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(**read_options).load('new.csv')
spark_df.show(3, False)
```

The  the above program produce the output below

```
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|header_col_1|header_col_2                                                     |header_col_3|
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|one         |two                                                              |three       |
|one         |{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}|three       |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```