# Handle JSON objects in CSV File and save to PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, json, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file which contains JSON objects as well as other data like String, Integer in it.
If I try to read the file as CSV then the JSON objects overlaps in other columns.

```html
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
100,ABC,{"abc": [{"xyz": 0, "mno": "h"}, {"apple": 0, "hello": 1, "temp": "cnot"}]},foo, pine

101,XYZ,{"xyz": [{"abc": 0, "mno": "h"}, {"apple": 0, "hello": 1, "temp": "cnot"}]},bar, apple
```

I am getting output as:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5
100 | ABC | {"abc": [{"xyz": 0, "mno": "h"} | {"apple": 0, "hello": 1 | "temp": "cnot"}]}

101 | XYZ | {"xyz": [{"abc": 0, "mno": "h"} | {"xyz": [{"abc": 0, "mno": "h"} | "temp": "cnot"}]}
```

**Test_File.py**

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark.sql.types import *
    
# Initializing SparkSession and setting up the file source
filepath = "s3a://file.csv"
df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true", delimiter = ',', inferschema='true').load(filepath)
df.show(5)
```

Also tried handling this issue by reading the file as text as discussed in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042848/how-do-i-prevent-pyspark-from-interpreting-commas-as-a-delimiter-in-a-csv-field)

```
'100,ABC,"{\'abc\':["{\'xyz\':0,\'mno\':\'h\'}","{\'apple\':0,\'hello\':1,\'temp\':\'cnot\’}”]}”, foo, pine'

'101,XYZ,"{\'xyz\':["{\'abc\':0,\'mno\':\'h\'}","{\'apple\':0,\'hello\':1,\'temp\':\'cnot\’}”]}”, bar, apple'
```

But instead of creating a new file, I wanted to load this quoted string as the PySpark DataFrame to run the SQL Queries on them, to create a DataFrame I need to split this again to assign each column to PySpark which results in splitting the JSON Object again.

Comment: Kindly review the answer and [mark as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the delimiter you are using. You are reading CSV with comma as a delimiter and your JSON string contains commas. Hence Spark is splitting the JSON string also on coma therefore the above output. You will need to have a CSV with a delimiter which is unique and will not be present in either of the column value so as to overcome your case.